# NodeJS + Mysql + Retorno de consultas do Banco

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, react, response

Boa tarde! Estou com alguns problemas com o NODEJS utilizando um banco de dados Mysql, já fiz diversas tentativas e não estou sabendo como resolver este problema.
Meu problema é que gostaria de consumir o retorno dos dados de um SELECT de uma tabela no back-end mas não estou conseguindo. Consigo imprimir a informação na tela usando o Insomnia (Postman) mas não consigo trazer as informações para o backend e utilizar as mesmas.

[image]Query que estou usando para consultar no banco (notem que nessa camada eu já faço console.log mas mais tarde irá retornar 'undefined')

[image]Configurações do banco de dados (ocultadas mas estão funcionando corretamente) e a função para execução da query, nessa tela eu peço para imprimir em JSON informações e ele retorna normal.

[image]Retorno das informações na tela do Front-End, ok

[image]

Informações do console.log que pedi para imprimir no back-end anteriormente, já me retorna UNDEFINED

[image]Quando peço para imprimir a variavel 'res', apenas me mostra todas essas informações

Bom, espero que possam me ajudar, muito obrigado!

Comment: Não entendi o que você quer que faça? qual o o esperado?

Comment: Eu gostaria de poder na camada do backend, poder tratar o resultado da query, mas não estou conseguindo trazer isso pois retorna Undefined

Comment: você está querendo trazer o resultado do retorno do banco de dados para que você possa visualizar no console esses dados?

Comment: Sim, isto mesmo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um modelo que eu utilizo é o seguinte

- `connection.js`:

---

```
const mysql = require("mysql");

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  port: "3306",
  database: "db",
  password: "senha",
  user: "root",
});

const query = (sql, callBack) => {
  return connection.query(sql, callBack);
};

module.exports = {
  connection,
  query,
};
```

- `TodoController.js`

---

```
const { query } = require("../connection");

module.exports = {
  get: function (req, res) {
    query("SELECT * FROM todos", function (error, result, field) {
      console.log(result); // resultado obtido
      if (error) {
        res.json(error);
      } else {
        res.json(result);
      }
    });
  },
};
```

- `express`:

---

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

const TodoController = require("./controllers/TodoController");

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.send("Service Init ...");
});

app.get("/todo", TodoController.get);

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("Service Web Port 3000!");
});
```

visualizo as informações também no console, pela linha colocada dentro do `TodoController.js`.

---

Pelo que pude perceber se fez errado a parte:

```
const teste = mysql.execSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM kit", res);
                                                       ^
                                                       |
```

passando o `res` e isso que pode estar acontecendo de errado porque ai não é variavel `response` é uma função que tem os seguintes parâmetros

```
function(error, result, field) { }
```

e nesse momento o problema, tem que seguir a mesma função que você mesmo declarou nas imagens.

Comment: Muito obrigado, era justamente este o problema! Alterei da forma que me passou e deu super certo, muito obrigado mesmo!.